# Как сохранить скин?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, оформление

Предположим есть несколько кнопок по которым можно менять скины и изначально будет например стоять скин "WEB2" и когда я захочу сменить скин на другой (например MacOS2) он мне поменяет, но если я выйду из программы и зайду снова то вернется тот же "WEB2".
Так как изменить скин так чтобы при следующем заходе он остался в программе по умолчанию?

```
sSkinManager1.active:=true;

sSkinManager1.SkinName:='MacOS2 (internal)';
```

Comment: записать настройки программы куда-либо и загрузить их при следующем запуске, применив соответствующие настройки скина.

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
<...>
  iniFile:TIniFile;
<...>

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   iniFile := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'config.ini'); // инициализируем объект, связанный с настройками программы, которые записаны в той же папке, где лежит программа, в файле config.ini
   sSkinManager1.Active:=false; // временно отключаем менеджер оболочек
   sSkinManager1.SkinName:= iniFile.readString('Skins','SkinName', '');// загружаем информацию о последней использованной/заранее заданной оболочке
   sSkinManager1.Active:=true; // включаем оболочку
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
   iniFile.writeString('Skins','SkinName', sSkinManager1.SkinName); // сохраняем при выходе, какая оболочка была использована последней
   iniFile.Free;
end;
```

Разумеется, необходимо также сделать обработчик на случай, если в ини-файле при загрузке не будет обнаружена информация об оболочке, а также на случай отсутствия ини-файла, как такового